# Mongodb replica set auto reconect don't work after down and up for nginx + uwsgi with several processes

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, uwsgi, mongoengine

Hi everyone I have next envirement for `python2.7.5`:

```
flask==0.10.1
flask-wtf==0.8.4
jinja2==2.7
werkzeug==0.9.1
flask-mongoengine==0.7.0
mongoengine==0.8.2
pymongo==2.5.2
uwsgi==1.9.13
```

and have next application 'app.py':

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.mongoengine import Document, MongoEngine
from mongoengine import StringField  

class Config(object):
    DEBUG = True
    MONGODB_HOST = ('mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018/'
                    'test?replicaSet=rs0')
    MONGODB_DB = True

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
MongoEngine(app)

class Test(Document):
    test = StringField(default='test')

    meta = {
        'allow_inheritance': False,
    }

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.test

Test(test='test1').save()

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return unicode(Test.objects.first())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 8080, True)
```

I have next nginx config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
    }

}
```

I start uwsgi as:

```
/path/to/env/bin/uwsgi \
  --module app:app \
  --env /path/to/env/ \
  --pythonpath /path/to/app/ \
  --socket /tmp/uwsgi.sock \
  --pidfile /tmp/uwsgi.pid \
  --daemonize /tmp/uwsgi.log \
  --processes 2 \
  --threads 2 \
  --master
```

I have two mongodb instances:

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /path/to/mongo/data/rs0-0 --replSet rs0 \
  --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
```

and

```
mongod --port 27018 --dbpath /path/to/mongo/data/rs0-1 --replSet rs0 \
  --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
```

And configured replica set in mongo console as:

```
rsconf = {
    _id: "rs0",
    members: [{_id: 0, host: "127.0.0.1:27017"}]
};
rs.initiate(rsconf);
rs.add("127.0.0.1:27018");
```

So it's working good. But when I down and up primary or secondary mongo instance then my application can't restore connection and I have next exceptions every time after:

```
...
  File "/path/to/app/replica.py", line 33, in hello_world
    return unicode(Test.objects.first())
  File "/path/to/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/queryset.py", line 325, in first
    result = queryset[0]
  File "/path/to/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/queryset.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    return queryset._document._from_son(queryset._cursor[key],
  File "/path/to/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 470, in __getitem__
    for doc in clone:
  File "/path/to/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 814, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/path/to/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 763, in _refresh
    self.__uuid_subtype))
  File "/path/to/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 700, in __send_message
    **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_replica_set_client.py", line 1546, in _send_message_with_response
    raise AutoReconnect(msg, errors)
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: No replica set primary available for query with ReadPreference PRIMARY
```

When I use `mongoengie==0.7.10` which use `ReplicaSetConnection` instead `MongoReplicaSetClient` in `mongoengine==0.8.2` then I have next exceptions:

1. Down secondary, get requests, up secondary, get requests:

   I have at first time:

   ```
   pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: 127.0.0.1:27017: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
   ```

   after:

   ```
   pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: No replica set primary available for query with ReadPreference PRIMARY
   ```
2. Down primary, get requests, up primary, get requests:

   I have at first time:

   ```
   pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: 127.0.0.1:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
   ```

   after:

   ```
   pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: No replica set primary available for query with ReadPreference PRIMARY
   ```
3. Down primary or secondary, up primary or secondary, get requests I have always:

   ```
   pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: not master and slaveOk=false
   ```

So two mongo instances just simple example. If I add one more instance (total 3), then:

1. If I down any secondary then all work fine. If I down and up one secondary and then down or down and up second secondary then all work fine too.
2. If I down and up two secondaries - some problem.
3. If I down and up primary or just down one primary (two secondaries availible) - some problem, despite that mongo elect new primary!!!

If I start one uwsgi process (without `--master` for two or three mongo instances) as:

```
/path/to/env/bin/uwsgi \
  --module app:app \
  --env /path/to/env/ \
  --pythonpath /path/to/app/ \
  --socket /tmp/uwsgi.sock \
  --pidfile /tmp/uwsgi.pid \
  --daemonize /tmp/uwsgi.log \
  --processes 1 \
  --threads 2
```

or run application with dev server:

```
/path/to/env/bin/python app.py
```

then application restore connection without problems after down and up mongo instances.

I have some deployment in production and sometimes connection to mongo instances can disapire (to several seconds). After that my application don't work normal before uwsgi will be restarted.

So I have two questions:

1. Why it's happenes with several uwsgi process?
2. How fix normal application work after down and up mongo instances?

---

**UPD1**:
I trying understand problem and now I have different behaviour for [`self.__schedule_refresh()`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/mongo_replica_set_client.py#L1449) when get connection exception when I down one mongo node:

1. For one process:

   1. Before this statement: `rs_state` have two members: active with `up == True`, downed with `up == False`.
   2. After this statement: `rs_state` have one active member with `up == True`.
2. For two processes:

   1. Before this statement: `rs_state` have two members: active with `up == True`, downed with `up == False`.
   2. After this statement: `rs_state` have two members: active with `up == True`, downed with `up == False` (no changed).

When I up mongo node then [`self.__schedule_refresh(sync=sync)`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/mongo_replica_set_client.py#L1481) also have different behaviour:

1. For one process:

   1. Before this statement: `rs_state` have one active member with `up == True`.
   2. After this statement: `rs_state` have two members active with `up == True`, upped with `up == True`.
2. For two processes:

   1. Before this statement: `rs_state` have two members active with `up == True`, upped with `up == False`.
   2. After this statement: `rs_state` have two members active with `up == True`, upped with `up == False` (no changed).

So look like mongo can't update replica set state (see [`__schedule_refresh`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/mongo_replica_set_client.py#L1027)):

```
def __schedule_refresh(self, sync=False):
    """Awake the monitor to update our view of the replica set's state.

    If `sync` is True, block until the refresh completes.

    If multiple application threads call __schedule_refresh while refresh
    is in progress, the work of refreshing the state is only performed
    once.
    """
    self.__monitor.schedule_refresh()
    if sync:
        self.__monitor.wait_for_refresh(timeout_seconds=5)
```

Comment: you need to have at least three replica set members for a new primary to be elected when one goes down. with only two nodes if one is down the other has to stay a secondary (as it cannot get the majority of the votes).

Comment: It's just simplified example, when I have three mongoe instances: 1. down and up one secondary - all work good, 2. down two secondries and up them - some problem, 3. down and up only one primary - some problem. And again all work fine with one uwsgi process or dev server.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using the uwsgi `--lazy-apps` option. MongoReplicaSetClient spawns a replicaset MonitorThread, and this thread does not survive the uwsgi worker process fork. `--lazy-apps` will initialize the pymongo MonitorThread in each worker process.

Comment: I check it and it's work. I am so grateful to you for this answer.

Comment: I've updated MongoReplicaSetClient to raise an exception if it's used after a fork, and I've clarified the docs. These changes will be released in PyMongo 2.6.

[commit 1](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/commit/9a5ded59e4e8e9f32b62dac266359470f7087b3f)

[commit 2](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/commit/0a54175b6cfcfc29bd4d9e990f365338c8a6435a)

Answer (score 0):

After a change in your replica set (no primary, new primary, etc.), the next operation will throw an AutoReconnect exception. After that one failed operation, the underlying PyMongo MongoReplicaSetClient will reconnect to the replica set, and future operations may succeed.

If there is a new primary, MongoReplicaSetClient will find it and future operations will succeed.

If there is no primary, no operations can succeed unless you set your ReadPreference to PRIMARY_PREFERRED. See the docs here:

http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/connecting.html#replicasets

The reconnection process must happen once per uwsgi process. So if there is a change to your replica set, you can expect one AutoReconnect exception per uwsgi process.

Comment: Ok at first time it throw exception. But the problem that future operations not succeed for the same process (many requests for same process, I see it in log by `pid`) or just `MongoReplocaSetClient` or `ReplicaSetConnection` can't reconnet when I use two and more processes for uwsgi. For example I have one uwsgi with two processes (`localhost:80` with `/tmp/uwsgi.sock`) and one more uwsgi with one process (`localhost:8080` with `/tmp/uwsgi8080.sock`) at the same time. And first after down and up mongo instance will completly down, but second will work fine. Did you try reproduce my example?